# Search engine optimization for .onion sites

Tags: onion-services, onion-routing, directory, website

Torch is an example of a darknet search engine. How can search engine optimization (SEO) be done to make an .onion site appear at the top of search results? how is darknet SEO different than regular Google SEO,
where either the number of clicks or paid marketing can move a site to the top?

Comment: I couldn't find much information on how the darknet search engine Torch actually displays onion services in the search results though the darknet search engine Ahmia is open source and you can find out how they do SEO on Github (https://github.com/ahmia/)

Answer (score 1):

It is totally up to "designer" of this Search Engine, is not?

Google has published their index-method, it is called [PageRank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank), so here you could at least guess a little bit... Nevertheless, nobody knows all of "The Kitchen" and war for the first places in Google's Search Results is endless...

You could try to tap your target, using kind of reverse engineering hooks.

Lets call your target - [Torch](https://torchsearch.wordpress.com/).

Lets guess, they shall copying Google's PageRank - because Google is #1.
So, you need to generate a "[Cloak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloaking)". Methinks, this shall be [onions sites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.onion).

Lets call the main one - "Directory" and lets place on it - links to 1,000 ( one thousand ) other onions-sites.

Backward, on all of this 1,000 new onions-sites, you should place links to this "Directory", to increase the PageRank of your main-site, called "Directory".

Also, you should place links to "Directory" on all possible places, like reddits, other onions-dirs( for example, https://ahmia.fi/ ), all hidden forums ( like silk road was ), etc...

Now you are ready.

I dont know how long, but you need to wait for day, or may be week, may be month, unlikely year.... Before web-crawler of Torch will index all your 1,000 sites and will increase PageRank of your main-site, called "Directory".

After awhile, you will check your "Directory" in Torch results, and it shall take some top-place.
However, Torch might black-list your site, because - it is not real, it is fake / dirty-cloaking shit..

And so on. It is Fighting of projectile and armor.

- You will generate new cloak each week/month/year. Guessing how they indexing.... How they far from original Google's PageRank idea...
- They will finding you, blacklisting you, and changing all their indexing-algorithms.

Comment: Your writing is very hard to follow and makes no sense

Comment: do you ever know how to setup onion hidden web service on your local-host?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the SEO topic is a big one, and that's my approach to it since 2000:

- Make a website really useful for the people, not tuned up for search bots
- Use all the matters possible to represent your content like  tags suggests you
- It's OK to make some records in HTTP headers and HTML markup both: I've never experienced the problem regarding to this, only a benefit
- Use microformatting!

Comment: this question is for .onion sites on the dark web where there's more to SEO than html and tags

Comment: As a SEO specialist myself since 2000 and as a custom SE writer I can tell you one non-trivial but sure thing: SEO is **exactly** the same everywhere. Depending on particular SE's there *can* be some specifics, but if even the custom SE is written properly - the checklist I provided **paired** with a good and useful content will give you a good SERP's